# WifiStateMachine error

Tags: android, android-wifi, motorola

After installing an update for my Moto G, device suffers from network failure with this in LogCat:

```
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: E msg.what=151572
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: ConnectedState
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: L2ConnectedState
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: X
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: E msg.what=151572
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: ConnectedState
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ processMsg: L2ConnectedState
1027-1087/? D/WifiStateMachine﹕ handleMessage: X
```

I found similar question at [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2624066) but unfortunately it hasn't an answer.
Has anyone else faced this bug and how did you solved it?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Got the same today..